# List all files in a folder - full path of the file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder in `C:\Name\Folder\` and in that I have several files.

I need to display the full file path of the files in that folder.

It should display all the files in the format of `C:\Name\Folder\file.txt`. My code is as follows;

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Name\Folder\");
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i) {
    string path = filePaths[i];
    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

It only prints the file name, but I also need it to print the full path of the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whats wrong with simply printing `path` variable?

Btw you can iterate files via `foreach` statement:

```
foreach(var path in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Name\Folder\"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(path); // full path
   Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)); // file name
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following,

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Directory.GetFiles` returns full paths. You're seeing only the file name because you call `Path.GetFileName`. Just use `path` if you need the full path.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the path within filePaths, what do you need the GetFileName call for?

Anyhow, for such info, it might be easier to use the [Directory/FileInfo classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx), which have all the required properties (such as Fullpath)