# How to filter file types e.g .exe in a C# console application

Tags: c#

Hi guys I'm new to C# and would like to know how I would code a C# console application that could look at `C:\Windows` file path and then the user can filter out the file type they want via text input!

Code added from comment:

```
string path = "C:\\Windows";
var result = new List<string>();
string[] extensions = { ".exe", ".jpg", ".win" }; 
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)       
    .Where(s => extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s)))) 
{ 
    result.Add(file);
    Console.WriteLine(file); 
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: Show us how you are loading the files

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: Use `Console.ReadLine()` to read input from the user.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962989/list-all-files-in-a-folder-full-path-of-the-file

Comment: While I have answered this question, I wouldn't be amazed if it was closed soon...

Comment: string path = "C:\\Windows";
                var result = new List<string>();
                string[] extensions = { ".exe", ".jpg", ".win" };

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(s => extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s))))
                {
                    result.Add(file);
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

Comment: don't seem to work and errors and wounded of there other ways of coding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple example to get you started, but in the future show us what you've tried first.

```
void Main()
{
    String filter = String.Empty;

    // prompt the user for a pattern (.e.g. "*.exe")
    Console.Write("filter: ");
    filter = Console.ReadLine();

    // create a reference to the C:\Windows directory
    DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(
      //fancy way for referencing %windir%
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)
    );

    // find all files matching ht epattern the user typed in
    FileInfo[] executables = root.GetFiles(filter);

    // iterate over them
    foreach (var exe in executables)
    {
      // and print the name of each match
        Console.WriteLine(exe.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)` to list all the files in a directory. The `searchPattern` parameter can take something like `*.txt`, `*.*` or `he*.*` like the `DIR` command in DOS.

You can use `Console.ReadLine()` to have the user input the search pattern.

Comment: @user3169776 You should **accept the answer** that best resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class from c#. It can return you an array of all files with a certain file extension